# How to change Bootstrap col-lg px parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

On this page http://getbootstrap.com/css/ is written that col-lg is for ≥1200px
so how can I change 1200px to 1000px, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is a custom setup for media query breakpoints. You can get it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) (already the right section for your needs)

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You can also use the LESS variables directly in LESS, but for CSS people just enter your breakpoints.